# bootstrap modal cannot open

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

```
<button
                                    style="width: 130px !important;"
                                    href="javascript:"
                                    id="wa_template_msg"
                                    class="btn btn-primary-d mb-2 mt-1 float-right"
                                    data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="wa-model"
                                  >
                                    Send WA Template
                                  </button>
```

The code aboves is use parallel with my wa-template model, code shown below:

```
<div
  id="wa-model"
  class=".wa_template_msg wa-body modal-body appt_body font_12"
>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inbox" class="font_12 mt-3 d-block">Inbox</label>
    <select
      id="waInbox"
      onchange="getwaTemplateList()"
      name="inbox"
      class="form-control font_12 p-2"
    >
      <option class="font_12 p-2" value="0" disabled selected>
        ------ Select Inbox ------
      </option>
      <!-- <% if (wa_inboxes & wa_inboxes.length > 0){ %> -->
        <% wa_inboxes.forEach(ib => { %>
          <option class="font_12 p-2" value="<%= ib._id %>"><%= ib.label %></option>
          <% }) %>
          <!-- <% } %> -->
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that no matter if I change data-target to "#wa-model" or ".wa-model" nothing works.
I am using EJS as a view engine in the backend.
The file structure is as follows:
"View" folder contains all view files even a file name by "conversation" having the button for which code is shown on top, that should pop up a modal whose code is in a file in directory view/partials the file name is wa-template.

I have no idea of bootstrap, my colleague use this code and now i have to deal with the problems. What i can assume is that there might be some problem with acessing modal from the file, there might be a need for a costume file which we can use to link the files; just a thought.

PLEASE HELP! I am trying to fix this problem from days.

Ok I have seen that we have under view/partial/base directory have a sidebar.js which have this code

```
  <div
id="wa_template"
class="modal right fade wa_template"
tabindex="-1"
role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="right_modal"
>
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title font_14 font-weight-bold d-inline">
        Send Template Message
      </h4>
      <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true"
          ><i class="fas fa-times" style="font-size: 18px"></i
        ></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

I checked this and solved the issue but not fully. The modal of sidebar pop ups but the content in file wa-template doesnot, the directory for this is "view/partials/".

Comment: Are there any errors on the browser console?

Comment: @KiranParajuli there are no any error.

Comment: acc. to bootstrap the target value should match the dialog id which is true here. I suspect that `href` in the button. Can you try removing that attr? See also: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo

Comment: @KiranParajuli i have edited the post, now the problem is that the content of wa-template file is not shown.

Comment: Hmm, so now this is not a bootstrap error. Are you using the Django templates (not sure)? I cannot tell more with the context provided above.

Comment: @KiranParajuli i am using EJS view engine.